# Quillen's model category - base change

Tags: homotopy-theory

The third axiom of a model category reads (Homotopical Algebra, Dan Quillen https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540039143):

> Fibrations are stable under composition, base change, and any isomorphism is a fibration.

What is a base change? There's a similar condition for cofibrations with something called a cobase change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base change is another name for the [categorical pullback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(category_theory)). The name stems from the fact that in algebraic geometry, you're often considering varieties/schemes $X$  over a fixed '*base*' ring/field (or even another variety/scheme), say $k$. This intuitively means that the variety is defined by equations over $k$, and categorically, it means that $X$ comes equipped with a morphism $X\to\text{Spec}(k)$. Now, if you have an extension/map of 'bases' $k\to l$ for another ring/field $l$, you can 'change the base' from $k$ to $l$, which in the view of a variety as a bunch of polynomial equations just means you're interpreting equations over $k$ as equations over $l$. Categorically, though, it turns out to correspond to taking the pullback of the given $X\to\text{Spec}(k)$ along $\text{Spec}(l)\to\text{Spec}(k)$. Extrapolating from this example, sometimes a general pullback is called a based change.

Dually, a cobase change is the name for the [categorical pushout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushout_(category_theory)).